# Why does MultiBinding with a Converter not work within a ToolTip?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, multibinding

For part of a fairly-complex WPF ToolTip, I'm attempting to use a MultiBinding to produce formatted text based on two properties. The problem is, the binding's MultiConverter receives `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` for each item in its `values` array.

The following works, using a single `Binding`:

```xml
<ToolTipService.ToolTip>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>
      <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="Amt" Converter="{StaticResource singleValueConverter}"/>
      </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>        
  </StackPanel>
</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
```

And so does this, using a `MultiBinding` with `StringFormat`:

```xml
<ToolTipService.ToolTip>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>
      <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat='{0:C} in {1}'>
          <Binding Path="Amt"/>
          <Binding Path="Currency"/>
        </MultiBinding>
      </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>        
  </StackPanel>
</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
```

**But a `MultiBinding` with a `Converter` does not:**

```xml
<ToolTipService.ToolTip>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>
      <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiValueConverter}">
          <Binding Path="Amt"/>
          <Binding Path="Currency"/>
        </MultiBinding>
      </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>        
  </StackPanel>
</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
```

The bindings in the last example don't receive any value. This isn't the case outside of a ToolTip - what is going on such that binding fails in this specific case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Try setting Mode="OneWay" on your binding.</strike>

Also, have you checked this problem and solution:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/wpf/thread/15ada9c7-f781-42c5-be43-d07eb1f90ed4

> The reason of this error is the
>   tooltips have not been loaded, so
>   DependencyProperty.GetValue returns
>   DependencyProperty.UnsetValue. You
>   should add some code to test that is
>   value is Dependency.UnsetValue. The
>   following code shows how to do this.

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) 
        return "";
    [...]
}
```

Comment: The Mode wasn't needed, but the solution on that thread *did* solve the problem. Funny thing: I'd read that page while researching this issue, had disregarded the solution, thinking "well, if the converter just returns `null`, that's not useful." It didn't occur to me there would be another pass through the converter with the correct parameters! Thanks much.

Comment: You're welcome. Had some fun in the past with multiconverters that included a weird execution with "Unset" values. Since then I'm watching the Ouput window like a hawk... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiValueConverter}">
                    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        <BindingCollection>
                            <Binding Path="Amt"/>
                            <Binding Path="Currency"/>
                        </BindingCollection>
                    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>        
    </StackPanel>
</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
```