# Multibinding with MultiConverter yields DependencyProperty.UnsetValue

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger, multibinding, imultivalueconverter

I have a list of `MyItem`. This object represents a shape with some properties, such as width, height and color. Using a converter, I'm trying to change the fill color from (255, r, g, b) to (`Alpha`, r, g, b) if my object is selected (I do *not* want to change the opacity). `Alpha` (double) lives inside my viewmodel.

My problem is that both values sent to the converter are set to `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`, no matter what I give to it. If I specify only the `Path` I would expect it to bind to my viewmodel, but it doesn't. Obviously, I'm doing something wrong here.

**Q:** I need the `Alpha` of my viewmodel and the `MyItemColor` of the DataContext for `myitem` (which I would assume is still the DataContext when inside the MultiBinding block). What should my `Binding` tags look like?

### XAML

```
<DataTemplate>
  <Grid>
    <Rectangle x:Name="myitem" Width="{Binding MyItemWidth}" Height="{Binding MyItemHeight}" />
  </Grid>
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
      <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
      </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter TargetName="myitem" Property="Fill">
        <Setter.Value>
          <!-- Simple binding works. WHAT is the difference?
          <SolidColorBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush.Color>
              <Binding Path="Color" />
            </SolidColorBrush.Color>
          </SolidColorBrush>
          -->
          <SolidColorBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush.Color>
              <!-- Change fill color if DataContext.Scale changes -->
              <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DoubleToColorConverter}">
                <!-- wrong? -->
                <Binding Path="Alpha" />
                <!-- wrong? -->
                <Binding ElementName="myitem" Path="MyItemColor" />
              </MultiBinding>
            </SolidColorBrush.Color>
          </SolidColorBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

### Converter

```
public class DoubleToColorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue
        // values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue

        return null; // New color
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

I solved it. I had to look for the parent control (which contains the items) in order to get access to my viewmodel. **A clarification of this, why it's good/bad, suffices as an answer!** I don't fully understand what's going on :)

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DoubleToColorConverter}">
  <Binding ElementName="myItemsControl" Path="DataContext.Alpha"/>
  <Binding Path="Color" />
</MultiBinding>
```

And...

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        return Colors.Transparent;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is part of the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273083/why-does-multibinding-with-a-converter-not-work-within-a-tooltip

Comment: Please see my update. I solved it, but a clarification of what is going on is needed. Thanks.